# c# FileBrowse changes path for the rest of my application

Tags: c#, filebrowse

i have created a form with FileBrowse control to load a file from.
the problem is, after i load a file the application looks for files in the path i'v selected instead of the 'Debug' directory (where files should be...)

how can i avoid it ? is it normal behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered Here: [Why does OpenFileDialog change my working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930816/why-does-openfiledialog-change-my-working-directory/1545005#1545005)

And Here: [Why the current working directory changes when use the Open file dialog in Windows XP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018970/why-the-current-working-directory-changes-when-use-the-open-file-dialog-in-window)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid it by not relying on the current directory being anything. Just consider what happens if you create a shortuct to your application, and change the startup directory.

If you want the *directory where the application is* why do you look for the *current directory*? You can get the directory of the application with the following:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

If this is a Windows Forms application, you can get it much easier:

```
Application.StartupPath
```

Answer (score 0):

This beahviour is part of Windows Common Controls (`OpenFileDialog`) and has nothing to do with your application configuration.

However, **you can** set the [initial directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx) in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Check the control for a property called RestoreDirectory.  Is this set to True?  If yes, try it as false.